# "unknown type name 'NSString'" error when trying to use Metal in a C++ project (vs code, mac m1)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, nsstring, metal, apple-m1

As indicated by the title, I got many "unknown type name 'NSString'" errors from files including NSObjCRuntime.h, NSObject.h, and NSZone.h. Then I added

```
#include <Foundation/NSString.h>
```

to main.cpp file, but the errors persist.

**c_cpp_properties.json**

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1",
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include",
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include",
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include",
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks",
                "/opt/homebrew/include",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [],
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-arm"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-I:/opt/homebrew/include",                
                "-I:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1",
                "-I:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include",
                "-I:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include",
                "-I:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include",
                "-I:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

**The "include" part of main.cpp**

```
#include <Foundation/NSString.h>
#include <Metal/Metal.h>
#include <MetalKit/MTKView.h>
#include <MetalKit/MetalKit.h>
using namespace std;
```

What did I miss?

Comment: `NSString` is an Objective-C object.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode will compile `.cpp` files as C++ files by default and `#import`s for Objective-C stuff won't work. You should rename your file to `.mm` or change its type in `Inspector` window on the right.

Since you aren't using Xcode, but rather vscode, it's much easier to just rename the file, cause then clang will automatically compile it as Objective-C++